# Unable to Stream events from AWS Pinpoint to Kinesis data Firehose present in different AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-pinpoint

I have AWS Pinpoint in Account A and a Kinesis Data Firehose in Account B, which stores the data in S3 in account B. There is an option in pinpoint to stream events directly to Kinesis Streams ( I am using Firehose for my use case. ). But using AWS console the Firehose stream present in account B is not listed in account A for generating the connection.

So I tried using IAM Assume Role for cross account access. I created RoleA in account A (Pinpoint) RoleB in account B (Firehose)

**RoleB - Identity Policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "firehose:PutRecordBatch",
                "firehose:DescribeDeliveryStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:firehose:*region*:*AccountB_id*:deliverystream/*FirehoseStreamName*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**RoleB - Trust Policy**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::*AccountA_id*:role/*RoleA*"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

**RoleA- Identity Policy**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*AccountB_id*/*RoleB*"
  }
}
```

Since It was not possible to connect firehose and pinpoint using console I used the AWS CLI and recieved error

**aws-cli command**

```
aws pinpoint put-event-stream --application-id *accA-pinpoint-project-id* --write-event-stream '{"DestinationStreamArn": "*accB-firehose-arn*", "RoleArn": "*accA-role-arn*"}' --profile *accA-profile*
```

**error**

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutEventStream operation: Destination stream validation failed. Check Destination and Role ARN values and make sure the IAM Role is configured correctly.
```

So Please help me out if anyone has done the cross-account connection between these two services.

Answer (score 0):

Hey looks like it's not possible to create cross-account connection between pinpoint and firehose present in two different account.